# MVC4 : call controller function result in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2012

I want to display an ID find in a datatable in a view. To do that, I do the following :

1. Create the function that will return the ID :

   ```
   public int getClientID(string login)

       {
           var context = new MyEntity(new Uri("host/MyWCF.svc/"));

           var userID = from persons in context.PERSON
                        where persons.LOGIN == login
                        select persons.USER_ID;

           int uID = userID.First();
           var cli = from client in context.CLIENT
                     where client.USER_ID == uID
                     select client.CLIENT_ID;
           int cliID = cli.First();
           return cliID;
       }
   ```
2. And, in my view :

   > Client : @{
   >   ((HomeController)(this.ViewContext.Controller)).getClientID(User.Identity.Name);
   >   }

Where HomeController is the name of my controller where the function is define.
But doing this, i've got the following error :

```
Can only specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip) after last navigation
```

At line `int uID = userID.First();`

So, why do I have this error (since I'm using the good namespace in te view) and also, is it a good way to work ?
Thanks !

Comment: You should first try to understand the MVC pattern...

Comment: I knew that melting the view and controllers wasn't a good idea AT ALL ! Quickely, how to proceed ?

Comment: Hint: the `getClientId` method belongs in the model. The controller should call it and pass the ID to the view.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.Action("Home","getClientID", new {login=User.Identity.Name})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to take first record inside your query itself like this,

```
public int getClientID(string login)

    {
        var context = new MyEntity(new Uri("host/MyWCF.svc/"));

        var userID = (from persons in context.PERSON
                     where persons.LOGIN == login
                     select persons.USER_ID).FirstOrDefault(); //Take First ID here inside query 

        //So you can use userID directly in second query. 
        //But you have to check for null as well.

        var cli = (from client in context.CLIENT
                  where client.USER_ID == userID
                  select client.CLIENT_ID).FirstOrDefault();
        //int cliID = cli.First();
        return cli ;
    }
```

---

To call Controller method inside View easly you can do this as well,

In Controller's Action which loads your view (generally Its Index action)

Add this line to create new dynamic function inside ViewBag.
ViewBag.GetClientID = new Func(getClientId);

And then add method in your controller

```
private int getClientId(string arg)
{
       //Your stuff
}
```

You can call this method inside View like this,

```
@ViewBag.GetClientID("Your Input string")
```

Let me know whether it works?